# Can I delete photos on my Lumix from my computer?

Tags: sony, sdcard, panasonic, panasonic-lumix, delete

Just got a Lumix DMC-S5 and I am happy with the camera.

I have some software that I use for a couple of other Sony cameras which automatically downloads all photos and deletes them from the card. The new Lumix shows up as a removable disk in the same way as my other Sonys so I had hoped to use the same process for downloading.

However, I get an error that the media is write protected (I get the same even in Windows Explorer). I have checked that the card isn't protected and I'm able to delete photos (and format the card) from the camera. Is this the way all Lumix cameras operate??

I can work around this by manually deleting all images on the camera after each download. I'd rather avoid this extra step though.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Alan

Comment: I don't know the answer to this specific question, but there actually are good reasons to delete them all at once, preferably by using the format feature of your camera itself, not the computer. For example, this will avoid filesystem fragmentation, which will make file recovery easier in the case of problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the Lumix DMC-L1K but I think this applies to all digital cameras.

Check your camera preferences for "USB mode". It should be set to USB Mass Storage. Other modes (e.g. "Auto") may allow you read access to the flash card but not write access. Write access is needed to delete files.

The mythical issues with fragmentation don't exist. File fragmentation effects read and write time, not space, and occurs mostly when many reads and writes are made while nearly full.

Comment: In my experience with recent Lumix cameras (FT20 and SZ3), they don't let you delete photos from my computer. Either in Pictbridge (PTP) or PC (USB mass storage) mode, both appear as read only in Windows.
You have to delete the photos on the camera. Or take the card out, and put it in a USB card reader.

Comment: Thanks, I'd resigned myself to it not being possible. It isn't too much hassle to delete the photos from the camera, as long as I remember to do it!